# Compiling OpenCV from source in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am working in a virtual Machine running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I have downloaded openCV version 4.0.0, and the most recent opencv_contrib branch. I created a build directory in the opencv folder, and ran cmake with:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE     -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local     -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON     -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON     -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_build/opencv_contrib/modules     -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..-DPYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3) ..
```

But then, when I try to run the make -j3, I get this error:

```
modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:24707: recipe for target 'modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 96%] Built target example_tutorial_SURF_detection_Demo
[ 96%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_tutorial_SURF_FLANN_matching_Demo
[ 96%] Built target example_tutorial_SURF_FLANN_matching_Demo
Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have confirmed that python version 3.6.7 is installed. And when I check in the directory where the object file in the error is supposed to be, it is empty. I ultimately hope to work with openCV in java, using openCV to capture a webcam in my javafx application.

Comment: Try to build from the release code, not the most recently ones?

Comment: Which release of opencv_contrib should I clone to get the "release version"? Also I though that 4.0.0 was the release version for the main opencv library since i didn't clone that, but download the zip from the opencv website.

Comment: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases and https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/releases

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to repond to this. It was just a versioning thing, checking out specifically the 4.0.0 version of the contrib repo fixed it all up

Comment: I don't suppose you would know why it would be refusing to detect JNI when I have the environment variable JAVA_HOME set to my installation directory to PATH?